# Prove that if $\lim_{k \to \infty}\dfrac{x_{k}}{x_{k+ 1}} >1$ then $x_k$ is convergent

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

[limit question][1]

Let $x_{k}$ be a sequence of strictly positive real numbers with $\lim \limits_{k \to \infty}\dfrac{x_{k}}{x_{k+ 1}} >1$.  Prove that $x_{k}$ is convergent and calculate $\lim \limits_{k \to \infty} x_{k}$.

**Attempted answer attached as picture.**

I am not sure if I'm actually answering the question properly. Also would I do the same steps to prove that limit is less than 1 and divergent?

Thank you inadvanced for any help.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't supposed to show something about the series $\sum x_k$?

Answer (score 0):

Here I proved, by mistake, that $\lim\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k}>1$ implies $x_k\to\infty$.

---

since $g:=\lim\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k}>1$, for some $\varepsilon>0$ we have $\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k}>g-\varepsilon>1$ for $n$ sufficiently large, let's say for $n$ greater some $N$.

from this, for $n>N$ we have $x_n>(g-\varepsilon)^{n-N}x_N$, and this easily implies $x_n\to\infty$ ($x_N$ is a fixed positive number, $g-\varepsilon>1$ so the geometric progression $(g-\varepsilon)^{n-N}$ tends infinity)

Comment: Other way round! The sequence is decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

since $g:=\lim\frac{x_k}{x_{k+1}}>1$, for some $\varepsilon>0$ we have $\frac{x_k}{x_{k+1}}>g-\varepsilon>1$ for $n$ sufficiently large, let's say for $n$ greater $N$.

From this, by telescope multiplying, for $n>N$ we have $\frac{x_N}{(g-\varepsilon)^{n-N}}>x_n$.
All $x_n$'s are positive, so we have $\frac{x_N}{(g-\varepsilon)^{n-N}}>x_n>0$ and by squeeze theorem, $x_n\to 0$ 
($g-\varepsilon>1$ so the geometric progression $\frac{1}{(g-\varepsilon)^{n-N}}$ tends to $0$).

Answer (score 0):

The hypotheses imply $x_k$ is strictly decreasing after some index. Since the sequence is bounded below by $0,$ it therefore has a limit $L\ge 0.$ Suppose $L>0.$ Then $\lim x_k/x_{k+1} \to L/L=1$ by the quotient rule for limits. That's a contradiction. Therefore $L=0.$